# Compiling a program

Tags: python, linux, installation, compilation

I am stuck following the instructions right on the first step. It says

> You need python to run setup. To see all options, run:
> `$ ./setup --help`

I type it and get `bash: ./setup: No such file or directory`

I checked `python3 -V`
and got

```
Python 3.5.2
```

In the requirements, it says Python 2.6 - 2.7 so checked that too `python --version`

```
Python 2.7.12
```

I also need CMake 3.0 - 3.11 so I checked `cmake --version`

```
cmake version 3.5.1
```

I don't understand the problem, why can't I proceed with the installation? Should I add the setup directory or script manually? It's Linux Mint 18.3

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Comment: `following the instructions` What instructions? Instructions to do what? What is the context? `In the requirements` Requirements for?

Comment: Given the error message, I would assume that the setup file is not in your working directory.  You have to be in the directory where that setup file exists, or that is the error message you will get.  What do you get when you type & enter the command "ls"?  What do you get when you type & enter the command "pwd"?

Comment: @Adam Winter Thank you, this helped and now it seems like a silly question I had.

I have another problem though, when I type the correct directory and setup --help, it says no <module> from autocmake import configure ImportError: No module named autocmake. But these files exist in the directory...

Comment: Not sure, but I'd take a wild guess that you don't have the needed compiler installed. 
 I would start by viewing the documentation to see what the dependencies are (other programs that need to be installed already).  Then, install those.  Otherwise, I'd take a wild stab at it and install the gcc compilers.  Also, seems likely the setup file is a Bash or Python script.  I would open that file and see what it's doing.